# normalizing euclidean distance

Tags: python, numpy, euclidean

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75463912/normalize-euclidean-distance-python) in SO but was told it is more appropriate here.

I'm trying to compute the euclidean distance with vectors of different lengths.

```
def euclidean_distance(n):
    L = np.linalg.cholesky( [[1.0, 0.60], [0.60, 1.0]])
    
    uncorrelated = np.random.standard_normal((2, n))
    correlated = np.dot(L, uncorrelated)
        
    A = correlated[0]
    B = correlated[1]
    
    v = np.linalg.norm(A-B)
        
    return v

v50 = euclidean_distance(50)
v1000 = euclidean_distance(1000)
```

The problem is that the euclidean distance is larger the more data points I use in the computation, and I was wondering about the best way to normalize the distances so that I can compare similarity between for example `v50` and `v1000`.

The SO answer in the link above suggested using `v = np.linalg.norm(A-B) / np.sqrt(n)`.
Is that a generally acceptable way to normalize the distances regardless of length of the original vectors?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! For what reason do you want to calculate these Euclidean distances, and how does any kind of normalization help you? (Yes, it keeps the distances from being large just because the dimension is high, but it is not obvious why this is desirable behavior.)

Comment: Thank you! I recorded two time series from subjects who belonged to one of four experimental groups. The idea is to run Euclidean distance on those two signals and compare the distances among the groups. However, because the experiment was self-paced, each subject has a different number of time points, and the subjects with longer time series have larger distances in general, so I need a way to normalize this information.

Comment: How, exactly, do you compute the Euclidean distance between two vectors of different lengths?

Comment: I mean I compute the Euclidean distance between two vectors of length 50 and then of length 1000, just like I did in my question. I would like to compare v50 and v1000, but since the Euclidean distance is larger the longer the vectors, I need to be able to normalize the distances.

Comment: the two vectors for any single individual in my study are of equal length, but subjects vary in the amount of time points.

Comment: It sounds to me like the problem you're trying to solve is 
`<X>`, and you're wondering if `<Y>` is a good way to go 
about it. Is that fair? Because if your real question
is "`<X>`?" then I would suggest only asking about that. As 
its written right now, the question appears to be an 
[XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).